# How can I implement a database-level multi-tenancy feature in Rails6 that allows me to dynamically add databases in runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, multi-tenant, ruby-on-rails-6, multiple-databases

I want to implement a database-level multi-tenancy feature that allows me to add databases dynamically. I haven't found a way to do this in Rails6.
Can Rails6's multi-database feature dynamically recognize a new database if it's added while the application is running?

If anyone knows, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment)? It has API to create new DBs during runtime and switch to them. I have used it successfully on rails 5.2 but haven't tried on rails 6 (YMMV). You can also leverage Rails 6's multi-database feature to create and switch to DBs in runtime (requires little bit of in depth Rails connection pool knowledge), but when I tried with rails 6.0, I was forced to establish new connection on every request, which made things slow and unusable. Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That was so helpful!